# ¿Sería correcta esta consulta sql?

Tags: sql

Tengo una bbdd con una tabla llamada polución con los siguiente parámetros:

- Valor
- Parametro
- Anio(año)

Y se me pide que muestre la media de todo el año 2016 de los valores por tipo de parámetro.

La consulta realizada es la siguiente

```
Select Avg(polucion.valor) as Media, polucion.Parametro, polucion.Anio
From polucion 
where polucion.Anio=16 
group by polucion.parametro
```

(Hay como millones de entradas, por tanto se me hace imposible comprobarlo)

¿Sería correcta?

Comment: Intenta ejecutarla de todas maneras y podrás comprobar por ti mismo si existe algún error. De existirlo se mostrará el mensaje de error y podrás solucionarlo tu mismo :)

Comment: aparte de lo que te suguiere @jachguate que considero correcto. Podrias acortar tu instruccion, colocar el nombre de tu tabla en cada columna, debido a que solo trabajas con solo una. ( polucion )

Comment: sin colocar el nombre de tu tabla en cada columna (Ej en vez de polucion.Parametro solo podrias colocar Parametro)

Answer (score 2):

La consulta que publicas en la pregunta tiene un error básico, y es que estás incluyendo el año en el select, pero luego no agrupas por él, por lo que la mayoría de motores (si no todos) rechazarán procesar la consulta.

Una consulta válida sería:

1. Quitando el año de los resultados, ya que ya sabemos que vamos a mostrar solamente los datos para el año 16.

   ```
   select Avg(polucion.valor) as Media, polucion.Parametro
     from polucion 
    where polucion.Anio = 16 
    group by polucion.parametro
   ```
2. O dejar el año entre los resultados e incluir la columna en la clausula `group by`

   ```
   select Avg(polucion.valor) as Media, polucion.Parametro, polucion.Anio
     from polucion 
    where polucion.Anio = 16 
    group by polucion.parametro, polucion.Anio
   ```

Obtendrás como resultado el promedio de los valores para cada valor de la columna parámetro (y año)